# classification with rejection and how to interpret a 2D ambiguous data

Tags: classification, visualization, mlp, interpretation

Let's say we're going to train a classifier with the full data set. There's also a reject logic for ambiguous regions in the data. So, at the end, the final system outputs **reject** or **0** or **1**.  That is, reject data points in regions with high ambiguity, otherwise use the original model predictions.

1. If you were to see a scatterplot with a boxplot accompanying it, how would you interpret the data in this plot?
2. How would you reject ambiguous data points?

[image]

[image]

Comment: How about setup as a binary classification problem, and in addition to the 0/1 label, also output a (calibrated) confidence of the prediction, then 'reject' those with low confidence?

Comment: FYR see [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/113458/classification-algorithms-that-return-confidence)